# Create ruler point in cm like input range

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to create a ruler, but a multiple point ruler, like in office words.

How do I create a min and max in cm or inches, help me with an idea or code.

```js
$('.x').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    start: function() {
        var top = ($(this).offset().top + 5) + 'px';
        var left = ($(this).offset().left + 5) + 'px';
        $('#parent').append('<div id="line" style="left:' + left + ';top:' + top + ';"></div>');
    },
    drag: function() {
        $('div#line').css({
            'top': ($(this).offset().top + 5) + 'px',
            'left': ($(this).offset().left + 5) + 'px',
        });
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('div#line').remove();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #eee;
}

#point {
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

#point:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #f00;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%
}

#line {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="point" class="x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com) **directly in the question**, not on some external site (that could be lost).

Comment: i dont know whyi cant embed code or in write using code editor. this my link https://codepen.io/ultramarshall/pen/OwXVxM?editors=1111

Comment: @Marshall I feel like this question is a bit broad. Its not a simple question, you are asking for a good amount of missing code. Maybe give it a try yourself and when you come about a more specific problem, come back and ask that.

Comment: @AndrewLohr Ok i'll try and com back again. thanks andreww

Comment: I don't know if this might help you, but in CSS you can use the units `cm` or `in` https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: @PascalGoldbach thanks for your reference